# What is the Frege equivalent to Haskell "readFile"?

Tags: haskell, frege

While preparing the Frege equivalents for the Real-world Haskell code examples (chapter 2), I could not find the equivalent for

```
:type readFile
```

What would be the closest match?

Comment: Update Mar 1 2014: As of the latest release, readFile is now supported. However, as this reads the whole data in one huge String, usage is recommended only for small files or when you really need the whole text at once (as opposed to line by line, say).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you will have to use [`openReader :: String -> IO BufferedReader`](https://github.com/Frege/frege/blob/master/frege/java/IO.fr#L213) function along with [`getLines :: BufferedReader -> IO [String]`](https://github.com/Frege/frege/blob/master/frege/java/IO.fr#L190) function. Then you can just combine the list of string into a single string.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I made this

```
readFile :: String -> IO [String]
readFile fileName = do
    file <- openReader fileName
    file.getLines
```

(This wouldn't be displayed nicely as a comment, so I made it an answer)

Comment: Perhaps this should be a library function, however, it would be very confusing if the name were the same as in Haskell, but the type was incompatible. Have an idea for a good name?

Comment: Hm, Groovy for example has a File.getText() when reading a full file into memory as text.

Comment: In perl, this would be `slurp` which is nice and sounds funny, but of course only intuitive for ole perl hackers ....